# Refreshing react-router results in 404 page

Tags: sails.js, react-router

I'm using:
- Sails v0.12
- ReactJS v0.14.7
- React Router v2.0.0

This is my Router:

```
render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
      <IndexRoute component={Layout} />
      <Route path="page1" component={Page1}/>
      <Route path="page2" component={Page2}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById("app"));
```

These are my Sails routes:

```
module.exports.routes = {
  '*': {
    view: 'app'
  }
};
```

My page currently is just two links to the page1 and page2 routes.

What's happening is that when I click on these links to get to app.com/page1 or app.com/page2, they render fine, but when I refresh on either it generates a 404.  However, the code (the links to the two pages) still seems to be rendering at the bottom of the page beneath the 404 page (image?).

How can I get this to serve the correct page from React Router?